# When I try to make Facebook login in my app, I get a "message = "(#100) Graph API for app id 1XXXXXXXXX called, but token has app id 4xxxx851";" Error

Tags: swift, parse-platform, facebook-login

I researched some post about this error,

Their answer didn't work.
I did put codes in p.list properly, 
I didn't put space between CFBundleURLSCHEMS key as well.

My questions are

1. What is this error message about?
2. How can I fix this?

If you need code, just comment me, I will stay on this post.

//// I made it again, and this time I got this that The display doesn't show anything, and when I touch it, it gives me,

> 2015-09-21 01:08:40.179 NoNa_App[3077:593233] unexpected nil window in
>   _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent, _windowServerHitTestWindow: ; layer = >

my p.list code is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"      "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
            <string>fb1686xxxxxx0</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>1686xxxxx00</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>bany</string>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>BNDL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
```

and my login page is

```
            import UIKit
import Parse
class CustomLoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func facebookLogin(sender: AnyObject) {
    @IBAction func facebookLogin(sender: AnyObject) {
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email"]) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
        {
            let mainPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainHomeTVC") as! MainHomeTVC

            let mainPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainPage)

            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

            appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = mainPage
        }

        //if let user = user {
         //   if user.isNew {
                print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
         //   } else {
                print("User logged in through Facebook!")
          //  }
        //} else {
        //    print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
       // }
    }


}

@IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

var actInd : UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)) as UIActivityIndicatorView

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

self.actInd.center = self.view.center
    self.actInd.hidesWhenStopped = true
    self.actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray

    view.addSubview(self.actInd)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func loginAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    let username = self.usernameField.text
    let password = self.passwordField.text

    if (username?.utf16.count < 4 || password?.utf16.count < 5) {
        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Invalid", message: "Username must be greater then 4 and Password must be a greater then 5.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")

        alert.show()
    } else {
        self.actInd.startAnimating()

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username!, password: password!, block: { (user, error) -> Void in
            self.actInd.stopAnimating()

            if((user) != nil) {

                let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "Logged In", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")

                alert.show()

            }else {
                let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: "\(error)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")

                alert.show()

            }

        })


    }

}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Comment: 015-09-20 23:41:17.210 NoNa_App[2562:524339] unexpected nil window in _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent, _windowServerHitTestWindow: <UIClassicWindow: 0x7ff9caf121d0; frame = (0 0; 375 667); userInteractionEnabled = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7ff9caf14740>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7ff9caf175d0>>
2015-09-20 23:41:28.755 NoNa_App[2562:524339] FBSDKLog: Failed to send AppEvents: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)"  ------ this is the first line of my editor(?) told about error

Comment: give me the relevant code.